# Effects of enabling DVFS in a CPU

Tags: cpu, motherboard, power-management

I came up with this energy regulating software called [Granola](http://www.ghacks.net/2010/05/01/save-energy-with-granola/) while reading at Ghacks.net

I downloaded and installed the software but you need to enable the DVFS function in the CPU.
I booted up and tried to enable DVFS in the CPU Configuration in my Asus motherboard(Desktop).
But in the description it said that enabling the feature might raise some compatibility issues with the power supply. And I'm afraid that I might ruin the CPU if I do this. 
Any suggestions, any one here who has tried this before? I don't know who the manufacturer of my power supply is. Would you recommend some software that can determine every possible info about the power supply.

Comment: What processor are you using?  From what I can tell under Windows > XP if your processor supports frequency and voltage scaling then most likely it will be using it unless "Cool 'n' Quiet" (AMD) or Speedstep (Intel) are disabled in the BIOS.

Comment: I'm using intel dual core 2.50Ghz